# TYPO3 7.6 downloads extension with category filter

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-extensions

I am new in TYPO3, I am working on 7.6.2 version I have to create a download PDF extension with category filters. When click on category it will display list of downloads having download icon,title and description.

I also used 'kk_downloader' extension,Followed all extension manual but I am getting this error on frontend page where list of all downloads will have to display -

> No data, possibly missing ID!?
>
> These are the SQL-Select-Parameters:"
>
> Tabelle = "tx_kkdownloader_images"
>
> where = "tx_kkdownloader_images.deleted = 0 AND
>   tx_kkdownloader_images.hidden = 0 AND tx_kkdownloader_images.pid IN
>   (37) AND tx_kkdownloader_images.sys_language_uid=0"
>
> group = "tx_kkdownloader_images.uid"
>
> order = "tx_kkdownloader_images.crdate ASC"

I don't know how to edit the extension and solve this problem. I also did not find any other download extension with category filter.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you correctly configure the storage page ID in the plugin settings?

Comment: @pgampe Thanks for reply. Yes, I configured the storage page ID in the plugin settings, still its showing this error to me.

Comment: And all downloads are stored on the page with the ID ``37``?

Comment: Yes. All downloads are stored on the page with the ID 37.

Comment: I do not know the extension and I have no further idea without looking at the code.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if the correct language_uid is set. In my case it was set to (all) -1 and the kk_downloader can´t handle that. Have a look in the table tx_kkdownloader_images witch language uid ist used.